# View with a reference to a reference as filter

Tags: 7, views, entities

Here is the structure:

---

- Content type: **Document**
- Entity reference (multiple) to: Specialization

---

- Content type: **Specialization**
- Entity reference (multiple) to: Department

---

I have Entity Reference and Entity Reference Filter modules installed.

Is there a way to create a view of documents and let the users filter the view by both **Specializations** and **Departments**?

Thanks in advance for any help on that!

Comment: How could you filter by both when there is no relation between Document and Department? Or do you mean a serial filtering, first filter by Specialization then by Department within that Specialization?

Comment: Document has relation to specialization and specialization has a relation to department. So if we know that specialization 1 is linked to department 2, can we not know that a document linked to specialization 1 would somehow be linked to department 2?

Comment: Ok, I don't know of a way to filter on this indirect relationship in Views. You can do this via a custom module easily because you can revise the SQL queries directly. See the answers by Triskelion in [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64020/drupal-views-relationships-to-an-indirect-referenced-contenttype](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64020/drupal-views-relationships-to-an-indirect-referenced-contenttype)